# Jenkins for multiple deployment on multiple server

Tags: maven, ssh, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and know how to create Jobs and add servers for JAR deployment.

I need to create deployment job using Jenkins which takes a JAR file and deploys it of 50-100 servers.

These servers are categorized in 6 categories. there will be different process run on each server but same JAR will be used.

Please suggest what is the best approach to create JOB for this.

As of now, the servers are less(6-7), I have added each server to Jenkins and using command execution over ssh for process execution. But for 50 servers this is not the possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is a great tool for managing builds and dependencies, but it is not a great tool for [Configuration Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management). If you're deploying to more than 2 targets (and especially if different targets have different configurations), I would highly recommend investing the time to learn a [configuration management tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software).

I can personally recommend [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-open-source) and [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home). In particular, Ansible works over an SSH connection to the target (which it sounds like you have) and requires only a base Python install.

Comment: More precisely, I am interested in deploying my application to 50 servers in one shot. Will Configuration Management tools help me with such a big deployment ?